# How to make sheets with add info?

Tags: html, css

For example like the page: flightdiary.net

Where you have to add the info like date etc. and it automatically displays it on a sheet? I have no idea how to code this. I don't know how to google it either

It's for a website I make for students. They will fill their homework etc. in this website. I would be very happy if you could help me.

Comment: Do you have a domain or website registered already or do you need to find something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `date input`, like so:

```
<input type="date" name="your-name">
```

[image]

### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/8ztLgn7b/

For more advanced usage you should Google for datepickers, such as [this one](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

If you were asking for dynamic placeholders, they're done this way:

[image]

### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/vr6kwcfL/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. How do the thing I write automatically transfers to the sheet i want?

Comment: @user7995862 what do you mean exactly? `date` input just works, if you need to send it's data somewhere (by saving the form) you'll need a `form` tag, most likely with `post` method. Learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data